# How can I add "Upgrade" Provision in WiX Installer?

Tags: wix, installation, upgrade, versioning

I've created a WiX Installer with `Product Version` as `1.0.0`

```
<Product Id="*" Name="My Application" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0" Manufacturer="My Client" UpgradeCode="182bbc7d-8cc2-4014-9e1c-29312598bxc0">
```

I'm using `MajorUpgrade` Element for Upgrading Installer as follows:

```
<MajorUpgrade  Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
```

**Scenarios:**

`Scenario 1:` Installing version 1.0.0 on already installed version 1.0.0

On installing the same version, the installer asks to either Repair or Remove, which is what I want and working fine.

`Scenario 2:` Installing version 1.0.0 on already installed version 1.0.1

On installing the older version, the installer throws error, A newer version of My Application is already installed and exits on clicking OK.

I want my Installer to display this error and continue installation by removing version 1.0.1 and installing 1.0.0

`Scenario 3:` Installing version 1.0.1on already installed version 1.0.0

On installing the higher version, the installer doesn't ask any thing and continues the installation by removing 1.0.0 and installing 1.0.1

I want my installer to ask for confirmation that whether to upgrade to higher version or to cancel the Installation

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

To allow downgrades you need to set the property "AllowDowngrades" in the MajorUpgrade element. Go through all the attributes in the MajorUpgrade element from the below link.

[WiX MajorUpgrade](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html)

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of upgrades is that they just happen. I think the assumption is that most people know what they are doing when they install an upgrade (or downgrade) and keeping intervention to a minimum is a good thing, and also in a silent upgrade install there is no way to ask for confirmation anyway - it just happens.

So in addition to allowing downgrades you'll need to add a confirmation dialog based on the property WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED, maybe add an upgrade dialog that is shown conditioned on that property. That's a little awkward because all you know is the ProductCode of what you're upgrading (that's the value of WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED) and no other information about the version that's already installed. So all you can say is that you are upgrading (or maybe even downgrading) the installed version. To get the information about the already installed product you'd need to query the system for the name and version of that ProductCode using something like the Win32 MsiGetProductInfo() API. That might require privilege (the UI sequence does not run elevated even if you are admin) so things get tricky pretty fast.

This is a fairly common question, so it's possible that someone has already done something, but a quick search didn't find anything.